SSRS Report Pointing to Incorrect Datasource When Deployed
We have a report project in Visual Studio with a shared datasource named "SITS".
The VS configuration is set to deploy reports to the following folder off home:
/ SITS TEST / SRS_Reports
The "SITS" shared data source we expect it to use is in the following folder:
/ SITS TEST / Data Sources
However, when I look at the deployed report it's actually looking here for shared "SITS" data source:
/ Data Sources
The report loads without error, it's just using the wrong database (dev data instead of test data).
When I try to manage the deployed report's data source and point it at the correct (test) datasource, it gives me this error:

The query behind the 'lov_EntryYear' embedded dataset runs fine on both dev and test databases, so...

I'm not clear why it's having an issue with the lov_EntryYear dataset when it runs fine on both databases that the 2 versions of the SITS datasource connect to.
How does a deployed report actually get the location of its shared datasource when deployed to SSRS? I'm aware that I have an equivalent "SITS" shared datasource in our VS project, but I don't think this is necessarily the same as the one on SSRS, nor is it clear how I could set the relative folder path to it when it's deployed to the SSRS portal. I've never fully understood this part as the shared datasource folder doesn't seem to form part of the VS project configuration properties.


It turned out that the company managing our SSRS web portal updated the credentials of the data source and it didn't have permission to access one of the views/tables in the dataset mentioned in the error. The dataset gets its deployment datasource location from the VS configuration files like it does for reports and datasets... I just couldn't see it when it I checked the first few times.
